# C# Check if any element in an Array Group is Null before comparing length

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, string-length

I have a statement that compares the length of elements in all string arrays.

```
string[][] allMyArrays= new string[][] { myArray1, myArray2, myArray3 };

lengthMismatch = allMyArrays.GroupBy(x => x.Length).Count() > 1;
```

However, `null exception` hits if any of them are `null`.

How can I get result that `lengthMismatch` = `false` if

1. Any, but not all arrays are null
2. One or more array(s) length are not equal

Comment: What about something like `x?.Length ?? 0` ? Or maybe not 0, then it is indistinguishable from an empty array. But maybe that doesn't matter? If it does, maybe -1 ?

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/02S6AZ

Comment: I like `allMyArrays.Select(x => x?.Length).Distinct().Count() > 1;` but it is much the same.

Comment: Unrelated: I'd also put that into an extention method as shown in the fiddle above.

Comment: Btw: If you _need_ them to be same length, why not use a [`string[,]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/arrays#multidimensional-arrays) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
bool lengthMismatch = allMyArrays.GroupBy(x => x?.Length ?? int.MinValue).Count() > 1;
```

On this way you still differrentiate between an empty array and a null array. If all are null this is `false` as desired.

You could also use an optimized way avoiding `GroupBy` on the whole array:

```
int firstLength = allMyArrays.FirstOrDefault()?.Length ?? int.MinValue;
bool anyDifferentLength = allMyArrays.Skip(1)
    .Any(arr => firstLength != (arr?.Length ?? int.MinValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is one of the cases where LINQ looks cool but not really needed.

Good old `foreach` might be better from performance and readability perspective, like this:

```
public static bool IsLengthMismatch(this string[][] arrays)
{
    int? lastLength = -1;

    foreach (var array in arrays)
    {
        if (lastLength != -1 && lastLength != array?.Length)
        {
            return true;
        }

        lastLength = array?.Length;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would disagree with "better from readability perspective"  and i doubt that the performance difference matters here.

Comment: Linq Version: "If you have more than 1 length, there is a mismatch" vs wall-of-code .. I'd sacrifice some miniscule amount of performance for the readability of _that_ Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Checks if at least one of the arrays is not null using the Any LINQ method.

```
string[][] allMyArrays = new string[][] { myArray1, myArray2, myArray3 };

bool atLeastOneNotNull = allMyArrays.Any(arr => arr != null);
bool allHaveEqualLength = allMyArrays.All(arr => arr?.Length == allMyArrays[0]?.Length);

bool lengthMismatch = atLeastOneNotNull && !allHaveEqualLength;

// lengthMismatch will be false if any, but not all arrays are null, and one or more array(s) have unequal lengths.
```